# Find interior points, boundary points, cluster points, limit points and isolated points of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Determine the interior points, the boundary points, the cluster points, the limit points,
and the isolated points of each of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Also, classify each of
the sets as open, closed, neither or both.

{$(x, y)$ ∈ $\mathbb R^2$| $0 < x ≤ 1$}
Interior points should be all the points in the set excluding (1,y).
Boundary points should be 0 and 1 because for each r > 0, the ball $B_r(x)$ contains at least one point in $A$ and at least one point in $A^c$

I am not sure about cluster points, limit points and isolated points. Should cluster and limit points be all points in the set?
A point $x ∈ \mathbb R^d$ is said to be a cluster point of a subset $A ⊆ \mathbb R^d$ if $A ∩ B_r(x)$ is not ∅ for all r > 0
x is a limit point of A if there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in A such that $lim_{n→∞} x_n = x$.
And the set is neither open nor closed

Comment: You _really_ need to check your understanding of the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2|0<x\le 1\}$. It looks like a pillar, not an interval. By the way, you need to carefully study the definition of interior point again.

Comment: Should interior points be all points excluding (1,y)? And so cluster and limit points will also be all points in the set excluding (1,y)?

Comment: Cluster and limit points do not need to be points of the set unless the set is closed.

Comment: So cluster and limit points will include (1,y)?

Comment: You're wrong about the interior points.   Neither 0 nor 1 are int R^2 so they aren't acceptable points.

Comment: @user286826 yes on the interior points. I think you should post your definition of cluster points and limit points and your reasoning about them so we can indicate the part where you misunderstand it.

Comment: No, on the interior points.  (1,y) is not an interior point though it is in the set.

Comment: "You really need to check your understanding of the set .. It looks like a pillar, not an interval."

Where in the OP was it ever claimed it was *supposed* to be an interval???

Comment: Ah, your interior point solution in the comments is correct.  The one in the post is not.

Comment: sorry, I edited it now!

Comment: @BigbearZzz I added the definition of limit and cluster points

Comment: You should write {(1,y)} instead of (1,y).  (1,y) looks like a single point with an unknown variable set to a single value.  And you shouldn't write 0 or 1.  These are points in R but not R to

Comment: Arggh.  The stack overflow phone app is one of the WORST designed things I've ever seen.  ... as I was try to to say... 0 and 1 are points of R but not R^2.  You probably meant {(0,y)} and {(1,y)}.

Comment: Yes I meant {(0,y)} and {(1,y)}